# How to stop jvm virtual machine from capturing SIGINT signal causing process to exit?

Tags: java, c++, jvm, signals

The main function is in the C++ layer, and the virtual machine is started by calling the `JNICreateJavaVM` function through C++. The C++ code layer also has a function to capture the signal.

The original intention is that the C++ layer captures the signal of <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>, but I didn't expect it to be captured by the Java layer. I checked the data and it is the Java layer's own signal capture function. I would like to ask how to avoid letting the java layer capture the signal (let the C++ layer capture the signal), causing the entire process to exit?

Comment: It is hoped that the java layer can avoid capturing the semaphore when calling JNICreateJavaVM.

Comment: Do you mean semaphore or signal? Please edit the question if necessary.

Comment: Don’t use the word “semaphore” when you mean “signal”.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify [the `-Xrs` option](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/java.html#:%7E:text=%2DXrs) on startup.

> - `-Xrs`
>   Reduces the use of operating system signals by the JVM. Shutdown hooks enable the orderly shutdown of a Java application by running user cleanup code (such as closing database connections) at shutdown, even if the JVM terminates abruptly.
>
>   - ##### Linux and macOS:
>
>     - The JVM catches signals to implement shutdown hooks for unexpected termination. The JVM uses `SIGHUP`, `SIGINT`, and `SIGTERM` to initiate the running of shutdown hooks.
>     - Applications embedding the JVM frequently need to trap signals such as `SIGINT` or `SIGTERM`, which can lead to interference with the JVM signal handlers. The `-Xrs` option is available to address this issue. When `-Xrs` is used, the signal masks for `SIGINT`, `SIGTERM`, `SIGHUP`, and `SIGQUIT` aren't changed by the JVM, and signal handlers for these signals aren't installed.
>   - ##### Windows:
>
>     - The JVM watches for console control events to implement shutdown hooks for unexpected termination. Specifically, the JVM registers a console control handler that begins shutdown-hook processing and returns `TRUE` for `CTRL_C_EVENT`, `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT`, `CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT`, and `CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT`.
>     - The JVM uses a similar mechanism to implement the feature of dumping thread stacks for debugging purposes. The JVM uses `CTRL_BREAK_EVENT` to perform thread dumps.
>     - If the JVM is run as a service (for example, as a servlet engine for a web server), then it can receive `CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT` but shouldn't initiate shutdown because the operating system doesn't actually terminate the process. To avoid possible interference such as this, the `-Xrs` option can be used. When the `-Xrs` option is used, the JVM doesn't install a console control handler, implying that it doesn't watch for or process `CTRL_C_EVENT`, `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT`, `CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT`, or `CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT`.
>
>   There are two consequences of specifying `-Xrs`:
>
>   - **Linux and macOS:** `SIGQUIT` thread dumps aren't available.
>   - **Windows:** Ctrl + Break thread dumps aren't available.
>
>   User code is responsible for causing shutdown hooks to run, for example, by calling the `System.exit()` when the JVM is to be terminated.

The <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is handled by the `SIGINT` signal (or obviously `CTRL_C_EVENT` on Windows). Keep in mind that you’re also responsible for handling all the other specified signals once you use this option.